# Pass findBy parameter to callback method afterFind

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I am trying to catch a certain findBy call (with afterFind) where:

if $results is empty (or the value you are trying to find is nonexistent), but the parameter value is found on another table, then it will modify $results to be valid

Some controller action got this:

```
$this->User->findByUsername("Bingo"); // yes, username Bingo doesnt exist on users table
```

User model:

```
function afterFind($results, $primary){
    if(empty($results)) {
        if(in_array($findbyparameter, array("Bingo", "Bingo1", "Bingo2"))) {
            // modify $results
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, how do I get $findbyparameter?

Thanks! All help will be appreciated!

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1026/findBy  should help

Comment: coder1984 could you be more specific? I have read that and didnt really help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not using these convenience methods, but you can pass the variable as Model property like this:

```
//where you search 
$this->User->searchPhrase = "Bingo";
findByUsername($this->User->searchPhrase);

//Model
function afterFind($results, $primary){
    if(empty($results)) {
        if(in_array($this->searchPhrase, array("Bingo", "Bingo1", "Bingo2"))) {
            // modify $results
        }
    }
}
```

It's not the prettiest method, but I guess it would work. Try to print_r($this) in afterFind method and see if you can spot somewhere the phrase which you search. I believe it's passed in the condition's array.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll be using this one instead. tried var_dump($this) on afterFind and found out that read() passes the params but not find (and findBy in effect)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a custom find type is what you're looking for. Custom find types have two states: `before` and `after`.

In the before you would setup your condition, and in the after you would check your data and modify if necessary. In both states you will have access to the query options.

Setting up custom finds is slightly different in 1.x and 2.x (you haven't mentioned which version you're using), so you can look up the specifics in the book.

In short, you would add add your the find type into the `$findMethods` property of the model and then add the corresponding method name to your model. Say you call your custom find type 'byUsername'

```
protected function _findByUsername($state, $query, $results = array()) {
    if ($state === 'before') {
        // add your condition to the query, 
        return $query;
    } elseif ($state === 'after') {
        // modify $results if you need to
        return $results;
    }
}
```

And you would call it via `$this->User->find('byUsername', array('username' => $username));`

In `$query` you would have the key 'username' which you can add to the `conditions` key of `$query`. In both states, you would have access to `$query['username']`.